# Help with translating calligraphy on painting

Tags: translation, calligraphy

I own this painting with extensive Chinese calligraphy.
Very grateful for help with a translation, as well as the name of/identification of the artist.

Thanks in advance,

Leikanger

[image: Painting with calligraphy]

Answer (score 2):

It is basically a brief introduction to Zhong Kui (鐘馗)

[image]

世傳鐘馗不第而逝 - It was said that Zhong Kui passed away without success in the National exams

民間傳說鐘馗進士 - Folklore said Zhong Kui passed and became an imperial scholar

鬼趣面式，嫁妹被一時傳為佳話 - The tales of his amusing faces and his marrying off his younger sister was famous among everyday folks

故世之有鐘馗佳趣頗廣泛 - Therefore, there are a lot of wildly spread interesting things about Zhong Kui

民間傳聞鐘馗驅鬼，故以鐘馗鎮宅 - People heard Zhong Kui could expel ghosts, therefore they used his image as a household protecting talisman

唐宋以來歷代相傳，風行海內 - Since Tang and Song Dynasties, his stories were passed along, all over the country

傳至扶桑盛行民間至今 - spread to Japan and became a popular tale until today

[壬戌](https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%A3%AC%E6%88%8C)(most likely in 1922 or 1982)冬月(winter)於京華(in the capital)半畝園畔 (besides the Half Acre Garden)鹵墨注題 (took up pen and written)

Comment: Thank you very much, greatly appreciated!